# How to complete the "Run 5000m with Frozen Scarlett" task in Temple Run 2?

Tags: temple-run-2

I'm Level 10 and one of three objectives which I need to complete is to "Run 5000m with Frozen Scarlett". First, I thought that I needed to wear Frozen's Artifacts, so I did that and ran more than 5000m in Sky Summit, but the mission wasn't completed. Then, I thought I should do it at Frozen Shadows so I tried it again, but it's still uncompleted. I chose Scarlett Fox with all of this. I'm really confused with this situation. Could you let me know how to complete this objective?

Comment: I've just found solution. Wearing Winter outfit for Scarlett and she will be called Frozen Scarlett. This is an ambiguous of Temple Run 2.

Comment: If you have found a solution yourself, you should post it as an answer. Self-answering questions is encouraged!

Answer (score 4):

You have to complete 5K meters in **one run** with Scarlett wearing her winter outfit (which you have to "buy", as purple wrote).  However, that may be difficult in the frozen shadows scene, so you can also do it in the "sky summit" scene.

Comment: When this was first released (1.20) it did need to be all in one run, but as of 1.21 (Mar 4 2016) it can be accomplished over several runs, even for those who already were assigned the objective.  This was more relevant for the "Frozen Guy" which for a while was only possible with a 50k single run as Guy Dangerous, but now can be done as accumulated over multiple runs, even for those who had already started it under the "do it in a single run" conditions.

Answer (score 2):

The "Frozen Artifacts" reward (that is, the earmuffs) apparently don't count for being "Frozen Scarlet."  For that, you need to be wearing her secondary outfit (with the ice ax, goggles and white jacket), which costs 60 gems to acquire.

Comment: The current update 1.23 makes this clearer by giving names to the various outfits- her gem-purchased winter outfit is now known as "Mountaineer" outfit and the corresponding objective states this more clearly.